# Which accounting software to chose for an independant worker?

Tags: windows, accounting

A friend of mine is starting her own accounting business in France, as an independent worker. Her clients are primary associations with up to 50 employees. She must handle :

- Pays and pay slips
- Financial reports
- Bills and invoices
- Balance Sheets

She did not specifically asked for it, but I'd say she also needs backups.

She asked me for advice because she does not know which accounting software she should use (neither do I). I took a quick look to some of the available solutions. There are tons of them (https://www.ciel.com/ or http://www.compta.com/logiciel/, for example), and I don't know how to choose.

Would you have some advice on:

- Which software to use?
- What criterion should she be looking when choosing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickBooks is a big name tool in the United States which does all of this and has a French version https://quickbooks.intuit.com/fr/, but I'm not sure if the French one does "Pays and pay slips"

To fill that other piece, potentially a big name provider like https://www.fr.adp.com/

I'd recommend making sure that anything she considers has been around at least several years so that it doesn't risk going out of business or potentially be lacking some key functionality or interoperability with software that clients / tax preparation services may be using.